# Why does using @Valid with @ModelAttribute result in exception?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, jsp

I get the **"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'person1' available as request attribute"** . Most answers to this problem say that I miss the **@ModelAttribute** annotation, but I use it and still get that exception.

I use multiple controller methods and want to have the same model to have different names in different methods. The problem occurs when I use **@ModelAttribute(name = "person1")**. If I don't name it, it works, but I have the same model in all the forms and get the same validation errors shown in all of the forms, even if I fill only one.

These are my example controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(HttpSession session) {
logger.info("opening index page");
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
modelAndView.addObject("person1", new Person("Maria Smith", null));
modelAndView.addObject("person", new Person("John Doe", null));
return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getPersonTree", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getPersonTree(@Valid @ModelAttribute("person1") Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "person1", person);
    } else {
        int id = databaseModel.getPersonID(person);
        person = databaseModel.setPersonTreeParents(databaseModel.getPersonTree(id));
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("getPersonTreeSuccess");
        modelAndView.addObject("person1", person);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/insertPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView insertPerson(@Valid @ModelAttribute Person person, 
BindingResult bindingResult) {
logger.info("insert person controller");
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return new ModelAndView("index", "person", person);
} else {
    databaseModel.insert(person);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("insertSuccess");
    modelAndView.addObject("person", person);
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

These are my example jsps:

```
<f:form class="form-inline" action="getPersonTree"
modelAttribute="person1">

<f:label path="name">Person Name:</f:label>
<f:input path="name" type="text" />
<f:errors path="name" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Get Person
    Tree</button>

</f:form>

<f:form class="form-inline" action="insertPerson"
modelAttribute="person">

<f:label path="name">Person Name:</f:label>
<f:input path="name" type="text" />
<f:errors path="name" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>


<f:label path="birthDate">Date of birth:</f:label>
<f:input type="date" path="birthDate" />
<f:errors path="birthDate" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>


<f:label path="gender">Gender:</f:label>
<%--                        <f:input path="gender" type="text" /> --%>
<f:radiobutton path="gender" value="male" />M
<f:radiobutton path="gender" value="female" />F
<f:errors path="gender" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Person</button>

</f:form>
```

I expected the custom names to work, because there are tutorials showing such examples with custom names, but I get the exception. So, my question is: can anyone show the correct way of dealing with multiple **ModelAttributes** on the same page with multiple forms, one **ModelAttribute** per form, but with different names?

Comment: Removing @Valid in above code removes also the exception, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `GET` handler:

```
modelAndView.addObject("thisIsYourCommandName", person);
```

In JSP:

```
<form modelAttribute="thisIsYourCommandName" ..../>
```

In `POST` handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPersonTree")
public ModelAndView getPersonTree(@ModelAttribute("thisIsYourCommandName") Person person, BindingResult result) {
    // ...
}
```

If your command name is "person" instead of "thisIsYourCommandName", You can do this

```
@ModelAttribute Person person
```

which is same as

```
@ModelAttribute("person") Person person
```

***So just do something like this:***

`GET` handler:

```
modelAndView.addObject("person", new Person());
modelAndView.addObject("x", new Person());
```

form for `Person`:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="person" ...>
```

form for `X`:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="x" ...>
```

`POST` handler:

`@ModelAttribute("person") Person person` or `@ModelAttribute Person person`

And:

`@ModelAttribute("x") Person person` or `@ModelAttribute Person x`

Comment: from your answer: the part  "form for Person" works for me, as I mentioned in my question, but I want to use it multiple times and it gives me same validation errors in all forms. The part "form for X" gives me the exception that I also mentioned.

Comment: @FalseScience That is because i think you haven't done this `modelAndView.addObject("x", new Person());`. You cannot use 1 command object for multiple forms to work differently. You need different command objects. (Just to inform, I wrote x in lowercase in my code snippets)

Comment: Oh, ok, now I tried it like you said: 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView index(@ModelAttribute Person person, @ModelAttribute Person person1, HttpSession session) {
  logger.info("opening index page");
  person.setName("John Doe");
  person1.setName("Maria Smith");
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
  modelAndView.addObject("person1", person1);
  modelAndView.addObject("person", person);
  return modelAndView;
 }`  

and still getting the same exception

Comment: Use `@ModelAttribute` in `POST` handler to get from model, not in `GET` handler like this. From `GET` handler just add the command objects to model is enough.

Comment: By `POST` handler i mean handler that handles form submission.

Comment: The post handler was already as you described: 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/getPersonTree", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView getPersonTree(@ModelAttribute("person1") Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
  int id = databaseModel.getPersonID(person);
  person = databaseModel.setPersonTreeParents(databaseModel.getPersonTree(id));
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
  modelAndView.setViewName("getPersonTreeSuccess");
  modelAndView.addObject("person1", person);
  return modelAndView;
 }`

Comment: Remove `@ModelAttribute Person person, @ModelAttribute Person person1, ` from `GET` handler parameters list.

Comment: it seems to work correctly now, but that exception comes again now, when there is a validation error in another form. In that form I use ModelAttribute person and don't even use the form with person1. But still it gives me exception about person1. Very strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185616/discussion-between-falsescience-and-minar-mahmud).